# How to implement Python code which include lengths of two lists and return matrix couples

Tags: python

Given lists

```
lis1 = [1, 0, 3]
lis2 = [2, 5, 0]
```

The needed result, only when these conditions are met:

> - lengths of lists are matching `len(lis1) == len(lis2)`
> - If both the digits have value 0, the English word for the greater digit in the two lists should be inserted alone instead.

```
one_two   zero_two    three_two
one_five  zero_five   three_five
one_zero  five        three_zero
```

My code is as follow and it doesn't give me what exactly shown as in the answer

```
def matrix(l1, l2):
    num_word = {
        0: 'zero',
        1: 'one',
        2: 'two',
        3: 'three',
        4: 'four',
        5: 'five',
        6: 'six',
        7: 'seven',
        8: 'eight',
        9: 'nine'
    }
    matrix = ''
    for i, j in enumerate(l1):
        string = ''
        for n, k in enumerate(l2):
            if num_word[j] == 'zero' and num_word[k] == 'zero':
                maximum = max(l1, l2)
                string += f'{string}\t'
            else:
                string += f'{num_word[i]}_{num_word[j]}\t'

        matrix += f'{string}\n'

    return matrix

print(matrix([1, 0, 3], [2, 5, 0]))
```

Comment: Your loops are in the wrong order. The outer loop should be `l2`, the inner loop should be `l1`.

Comment: You don't need to use `enumerate()`. You should only be using the values in the lists, not the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're iterating in the wrong order. Each row in the output is for the same value in `lis2`, so the outer loop should be over `l2`, not `l1`.
2. `num_word[i]` uses the list index rather than the list value. You should be using `num_word[j]` and `num_word[k]`. Using more meaningful variable names should help avoid bugs like this.
3. There's no need to use `enumerate` at all, since nothing in the algorithm depends on list indexes.
4. You're not calculating `maximum` correctly. You're setting it to the larger of the two lists, not the maximum element in both lists. You can combine the lists with `l1+l2`, then call `max()`.
5. After you calculate `maximum`, you're not using it, you're substituting `string` into itself. You need to get the corresponding element of `num_words`
6. You don't need `string`, you can simply concatenate directly to `matrix`.
7. There's no need to recalculate `maximum` every time, since it doesn't change. Get it once before the loop.
8. To check for both numbers being zero, check the numbers rather than the words.
9. You never check whether the lengths are equal.

```
def matrix(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return ""

    num_word = {
        0: 'zero',
        1: 'one',
        2: 'two',
        3: 'three',
        4: 'four',
        5: 'five',
        6: 'six',
        7: 'seven',
        8: 'eight',
        9: 'nine'
    }
    matrix = ''
    maximum = num_word[max(l1 + l2)]
    for num2 in l2:
        for num1 in l1:
            if num1 == 0 and num2 == 0:
                matrix += f'{maximum}\t'
            else:
                matrix += f'{num_word[num1]}_{num_word[num2]}\t'

        matrix += '\n'

    return matrix

print(matrix([1, 0, 3], [2, 5, 0]))
```